# How to pin applications in xfce4?

Tags: xfce, minecraft, xfce4-terminal

In order to run the Minecraft launcher for Linux, I have to run a command that brings up the window.

Is there a way to pin it (Minecraft launcher) to the desktop or an easy access place so that all I have to do is just double click the launcher?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Release: 12.04  LTS

Comment: You want to add minecraft to [this](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-yW_8Nwp2KMo/UTOgvhxUKrI/AAAAAAAAD2s/GWEPWNzVpNk/s1600/app-launchers.png) panel? Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you need to add an application launcher. You can create one from the xfce4 settings and then modify it with launcher name and the command.